# Return multiple fields from django model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

As the title says, I want to return two fields (semester, subject) separately from semSubject model and access them in Sem1Attendance.

Code as follows,

**models.py**

```
class semSubject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=9,default="Theory")
    sem = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Sem1Attendance(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.ForeignKey(Sem1Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(semSubject,related_name='sem_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(semSubject, related_name='sub_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

EDIT:
This is how it appears in the admin panel,
https://shorturl.at/dFZ58, I want it to display semester and subjects separately.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain more about your question like where you want to use this? If exist sharing your view function would be better to help people understand your problem.

Comment: I want to use this in the admin panel, I'm not using any views.

Comment: I have registered the model in the admin panel and I am managing it from there. So when I try to add records into the attendance model, it is showing the objects of the semSubject model and not individual records in it.